# Trying to get LogicSigAccount from algodClient.compile(sig)

Tags: javascript, algorand

Using the JavaScript SDK for Algorand.

Does anyone know how to go from `algodClient.compile(sig)` to a `LogicSigAccount`?

I can do it using the Python SDK, but I can't seem to translate it to JS. Here's the python in case that's useful: `lsig = LogicSigAccount(base64.decodebytes(response["result"].encode()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const lsig = new algosdk.LogicSigAccount(
        new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(compiledSig.result, "base64"))
      );
```